# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module - Cordova

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ecmascript-6, phonegap

I am simply trying to access my common application variable/function from `main.js` file. **using ES6- Import Export.**

```
export var APP_NAME= "MyPOC"; - File main.js
```

Importing now in other javascript file- home.js,

```
import * as mainparams from './main.js';
console.log("variable_name:"+ mainparams.APP_NAME);
```

OR

```
import {APP_NAME} from './main.js';
console.log("variable_name:"+ APP_NAME);
```

`Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

**The same thing is working while I am importing in my HTML page** - `index.html`

```
<script type="module">
         import {APP_NAME} from './js/main.js';
          console.log("variable_name: "+ APP_NAME); 
</script>
Result - Print in console - variable_name: MyPOC
```

What I did to fix the issue:

1. I checked the js file path, both js are in the same folder
2. Cross-check the `cordova-plugin-whitelist` package installed already
3. I tried to add `"type" : "module"` in package.json - `Show me issue on terminal can't support ES6`
4. Added `<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>` - `Result: "unexpected token <"`

None of the above action items working for me. I just want to normalize my code in different Javascript files for better code readability.

**Using**: HTML, CSS. JS, JQuery, Cordova, Phonegap Platform: Android, Browser

1. [ES6- Java Script Import-Export](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/es6-import-and-export/#:%7E:text=With%20the%20help%20of%20ES6,more%20members%20in%20a%20module.)
2. [Cordova WhileList Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist)
3. [Add module in package.json file or use module directly](https://nkaushik.com/javascript/solved-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-module/#:%7E:text=SyntaxError%3A%20Cannot%20use%20import%20statement,features%20in%20your%20JavaScript%20project.&text=It%20will%20throw%20this%20error.&text=It%20also%20shows%20one%20warning,%22module%22%20in%20the%20package.)

Please help me out and thanks for your time to understand my issue.

Comment: The *"unexpected token <"* message you got might be because a server returned HTML (maybe as a result of 404 error) for the `main.js` request. At any point, I think you want to add the other module that is not `main.js`

Comment: You've to add the `module` attribute to the script tag loading home.js.

Comment: @Teemu Yes i did try - <script type="module" src="main.js"/> in my home.js and that return me Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Comment: Please re-read my comment ...